# How to export separate spreads to pdf in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export

I created a 8-pages long, "facing-pages" document and would like to export just 3 spreads (pages:2-3,4-5,6-7)to pdf files separately. Do you know how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export, type "2,4,6" in the `Range` field and check `Spreads` below. This will create a single pdf with pages 2-7 saved as spreads. If you need a separate pdf for each spread, then export page 2 with `Spreads` checked, then page 4  with `Spreads` checked, then page 6  with `Spreads` checked. Image attached.

[image: pdf export options]